# Can't catch a click event on a button in typescript

Tags: typescript

Can't catch a click event on a button in typescript.
I have very simple set up: a button in `index.html` and a short code that tries to detect whether or not the button was clicked, but it is not working. Here are these two files:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Typescript App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main" class="main">
      <div id="display">
        <button id="testSmth">Test Something</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./index.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is `index.ts`:

```
console.log('Starting')

class TestSmth {
    testSmthBut: HTMLObjectElement | null;
    clicked: boolean;

    constructor(){
        this.testSmthBut = document.querySelector('#testSmth');
        this.clicked = false;
        this.testSmthBut?.addEventListener('click', this.clickHandler);

    }

    clickHandler = (): void => { 
        this.clicked = true;
        console.log('clicked');
    }​;​
}

function sleep(milliseconds: number): void {
    const date = Date.now();
    let currentDate = null;
    do {
      currentDate = Date.now();
    } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}

function lookigForClick(foo: TestSmth): void {
    if (foo.clicked === true) {
        console.log('yehhhh!!!');
        return;
    }
    else {
        console.log('still waiting');
        sleep(1000);
        lookigForClick(foo);
    }
} 

console.log('A')
let testsmth = new TestSmth();
lookigForClick(testsmth);
```

After compiling to `js` and starting a local server with `node.js` I can't get the recursion to stop no matter how often I clicked the button (see image below). What do I do wrong? Thanks :)
[image]

EDIT:

1. TS version 4.3.5
2. Project structure:

> ```
> -project_folder:
> ---tsconfig.json
> ---package.json
> ---src:
> ------index.ts
> ------index.html
> ```

3. How to compile and start server:
   got to the project_folder and run

> ```
> npm install
> npm start
> ```

4. package.json

> ```
> {
>   "name": "carcassone-parcel",
>   "version": "1.0.0",
>   "description": "",
>   "main": "index.js",
>   "scripts": {
>     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
>     "start": "parcel serve src/index.html",
>     "watch": "parcel watch src/index.html"
>   },
>   "author": "",
>   "license": "ISC",
>   "devDependencies": {
>     "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.11.0",
>     "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.11.0",
>     "eslint": "^7.16.0",
>     "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.1.0",
>     "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.0",
>     "parcel": "^1.12.4",
>     "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4",
>     "prettier": "^2.2.1",
>     "typescript": "^4.3.5"
>   }
> }
> ```

4. tsconfig.json

> ```
> {
>     "compilerOptions": {
>       "target": "es5",
>       "module": "esnext",
>       "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
>       "jsx": "react",
>       "sourceMap": true,
>       "strict": true,
>       "moduleResolution": "node",
>       "baseUrl": "./src",
>       "paths": {
>         "~/*": ["./*"]
>       },
>       "typeRoots": ["src/images/"],
>       "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
>       "esModuleInterop": true
>     },
>     "include": ["src/**/*"]
> }
> ```

Comment: What is your Typescript version?

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi I added some info to the problem description. TS version is 4.3.5.

Comment: Please add `console.log(this.testSmthBut);` before `addEventListener` line and tell me it is null or not

Comment: the output says "<button id="testSmth">" looks good, right?

Comment: Why do you have ` <script src="./index.ts"></script>` when you must have `index.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've created an infinite loop. To make sense for you just run `lookigForClick` method in playground and see the browser is hanging.

This is [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgziA2CmB00QHMAUByAygFwIYCdsBLMZdASgChLhpcIIACAFVgm0wFtsALRgb0qNhjbGw7ceAIQCu2AFyMAEswCyAGQDyAIwBWsYNgCicTrDDZGAH0ZgZ0aAG4hI2kWABrWABNF2kDCwuGDOLsKgkNj4MoYg%20KjkgiLJojxEEPBi7Fy8spYAvIzeIMAyZhbwAI4ysPgAnpiwcLHx6ADEWRK8FM4pIrzp8G6ePoyFAGa40BCwvX2pg5050nIA-PC43t5GAG7m2OrpYmC1GMMe6AA0CxnnSsHecPjkockAvtTJdw9PY4wJih2ICI3jGAD4BIwwikBrdoO4vKDClEanM%20hEoHBECgzvCRt4etC3oBoAkcxMoH0o4xkYEMRHAjAgcFgAAdUJwiA50gZwN4IIo7JxtLVyIDgaCkq5wOwirgxH8ACJyhBgEAAdwSaMYcEspXw%20H2SvlhTsDi1xQE0PCMn1huViuV8FVGpeRMYarScH%20eoNFiNsEYAFpZfKADyMDlcmYRPmuynU2nEBlIEAeIjIABicQAwniPKhxgFFKxspJRYwgSDLckiON-oWQEM86N8q3RNFYORq-MMYFsWh0HVYDwRzwAIQTwnzRgG7A2kJE6FNGbd9HSvtIAfsTnQd24IjEUhT%20ZM2Cs1AARgADDfXdOU2nMzm8wWAneRB83lCaOusZuMAAghQlA6qI4gQJIfwnGqLDiMsmogQEj5ZvguYIqgnQQbwLxAA) link that is hanging because of infinite loop.

**Solution**

Instead of custom infinite loop use `setInterval` methods like this:

```
function lookigForClick(foo: TestSmth): void {
    if (foo.clicked === true) {
        console.log('yehhhh!!!');
        return;
    }
    else {
        console.log('still waiting');
    }
} 
console.log('A');
let testsmth = new TestSmth();

window.setInterval(()=>{
    lookigForClick(testsmth)
},1000)
```

Here is [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-lit-html-redux-basic-fdbhcc?file=index.ts) working sample that I created for you.

**Update**

It seems you need custom infinite loop. So you have two options:

1.sleep methods must be `async` to prevent browser freezing. Note that In this way you don't really wait for another action you just have working infinite loop.

```
function delay(ms: number) {
    return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms) );
}
```

And then use it in `lookigForClick` methods like this:

```
function lookigForClick(foo: TestSmth): void {
    if (foo.clicked === true) {
        console.log('yehhhh!!!');
        return;
    }
    else {
      (async () => { 
        console.log('still waiting');

         await delay(1000);

        lookigForClick(foo);
      })();   
    }
}
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgziA2CmB00QHMAUByAygFwIYCdsBLMZdASgChLhpcIIACAFVgm0wFtsALRgb0qNhjbGw7ceAIQCu2AFyMAEswCyAGQDyAIwBWsYNgCicTrDDZGAH0ZgZ0aAG4hI2kWABrWABNF2kDCwuGDOLsKgkNj4MoYg%20KjkgiLJojxEEPBi7Fy8spYAvIzeIMAyZhbwAI4ysPgAnpiwcLHx6ADEWRK8FM4pIrzp8G6ePoyFAGa40BCwvX2pg5050nIA-PC43t5GAG7m2OrpYmC1GMMe6AA0CxnnSsHecPjkockAvtTJdw9PY4wJih2ICI3jGAD4BIwwikBrdoO4vKDClEanM%20hEoHBECgzvCRt4etC3oBoAkcxMoH0o4xkYEMRHARSauDqqE4EEUdk42lq5AE0PwsGwMnwYFssAA7owAAr4ECcdKwVCMAWYvbgxgzbDMIhmEByVAqmB7a5s3kvCnUam04gMiBwWAAB1ZRAcCoi3nZtjK3OegOBoKSrnA7CKuDEfwAImGEGAQOKEmjGHBLKV8AKLFHw4U7A5E8U%20ejhensJnYJHo-BY-Hze9GOK0nB-qni6XGABaUPhgA8jHlrpm7og5spVrpDKQIA8RGQADE4gBhPEeVDjAKKVjZSTkP0ggsiIjjf6rkBDJejfIX0TRWC8wPo4OBbFodB1WA8d88ACE38J82VguFEIiWhJoZj3ZJUHoOpaX%20Xl8ghfgoT-DFHyQZ92BdaA61wIhiFIQloRSXBxRwyxvCZFkAEYAAZaPNQiRAnKdZwXJcVwCGsUjecgExEYC3ihGgHyxNCMAAQQoShk1EcQIEkP4TklDcuh4BMpICZi53wRcEVQTo5N4F4gA)

2. **Simple and better** way is create actual waiting methods. For example if I call `sleep(10000)` I have to wait 10 seconds to execute next line code!

Again Note that your sleep method didn't actually wait. To test that just call `sleep(10000)` and see immediately `console.log('still waiting');` executed.

So to have actual wait method simply use `window.setTimeout` like this:

```
function lookigForClick(foo: TestSmth): void {
    if (foo.clicked === true) {
        console.log('yehhhh!!!');
        return;
    }
    else {
      window.setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log('still waiting');

        lookigForClick(foo);
      }, 10000);   
    }
}
```

Now run this [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=44&ssc=3&pln=32&pc=1#code/MYewdgziA2CmB00QHMAUByAygFwIYCdsBLMZdASgChLhpcIIACAFVgm0wFtsALRgb0qNhjbGw7ceAIQCu2AFyMAEswCyAGQDyAIwBWsYNgCicTrDDZGAH0ZgZ0aAG4hI2kWABrWABNF2kDCwuGDOLsKgkNj4MoYg%20KjkgiLJojxEEPBi7Fy8spYAvIzeIMAyZhbwAI4ysPgAnpiwcLHx6ADEWRK8FM4pIrzp8G6ePoyFAGa40BCwvX2pg5050nIA-PC43t5GAG7m2OrpYmC1GMMe6AA0CxnnSsHecPjkockAvtTJdw9PY4wJih2ICI3jGAD4BIwwikBrdoO4vKDClEanM%20hEoHBECgzvCRt4etC3oBoAkcxMoH0o4xkYEMRHARSauDqqE4EEUdk42lq5AE0PwsGwMnwYFssAA7owAAr4ECcdKwVCMAWYvbgxgzbDMIhmEByVAqmB7a5s3kvCnUam04gMiBwWAAB1ZRAcCoi3nZtjK3OegOBoKSrnA7CKuDEfwAImGEGAQOKEmjGHBLKV8AKLFHw4U7A5E8U%20ejhensJnYJHo-BY-Hze9GOK0nB-qni6XGABaUPhgA8jHlrpm7og5spVrpDKQIA8RGQADE4gBhPEeVDjAKKVjZSTkP0ggsiIjjf6rkBDJejfIX0TRWC8wPo4OBbFodB1WA8d88ACE38J82VguFEIiWhJoZj3ZJxRIYpxXgTVtV1fUEnyME7xSDFHyQZ92BdaA61wIhiFIQloWSCcp1nBclxXAIaxSN5rgARgABhYpiXhEYC3ihGgHyxTCMAAQQoShk1EcQIEkP4TklDcuh4BMRICci53wRcEVQToJN4F4gA) link and see after each 10 seconds this `console.log('still waiting');` executed.

Comment: I understand your solution thanks! But I do not understand why infinite loop was a problem? I actually need to create a simple game (something like Patience) for my study project and needed to use typescript+html for game and UI creation. My plan was to use the while(true) inside which a user will perform repeated actions (e.g. draw card, put it at right place at the board) over and over again till there are cards in the deck, and if there were no cards left then the while loop would be interrupted with break.

Comment: I also noticed that this code works as if there were a while loop console.log('A');
let butt = document.getElementById('testSmth')!;
butt.onclick = function(e){
    console.log('works!')
    alert('click');
} WITHOUT the while loop, would appreciate a hint regarding why it works as if there was a while loop. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @tommy I spend two hours for the answer. I hope you get the answer and it helps. Simply use `Simple and better` I explained in my answer and probably you don't have any problem :)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answers! I've tested on my local machine and it worked. Though the 1st Option yielded a result which I would expect, but the 2nd option yielded the output in the following sequence: (1) Starting index.ts:1:8
(2) A index.ts:47:8
(3) still waiting 6 index.ts:41:20
(4) clicked index.ts:18:16
(5) still waiting index.ts:41:20
(6) yehhhh!!!. I don't understand why after clicking the button, the execution still goes one time into the else branch (see above output points 4 and 5), would appreciate any hint!? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In principle as far as I understand one can use the above solution to wait for any particular event coming from the UI. If I would need to read in some input from UI (e.g. some user defined values) and the code execution should not continue before those values are red in, can one do it without creating an infinite loop, or the above solution is the only way? Thank you! This is my last question :)

Comment: @tommy It is good idea to upvote or even accept the answer helped you!! :)
And for last question you just need event. Instead of wait, you can listen to change of text box or any complicated event and then do what you want

Comment: Sure, just wanted to finish the discussion, thanks a lot! Did you mean listen inside the infinite loop / recursion, or is there any other way? Thanks

Comment: Did you mean listen inside the infinite loop / recursion, or is there any other way? Thanks

Comment: No I don't think you need to `infinite loop`  you just need listen to event when user action. like change the text box value or something else

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip, I'll try it post later how it worked for me.